# Copy column from one sheet to another using VBA (with loop)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to copy columns from Sheet 1 and paste them in Sheet 2, particularly in the next empty column on sheet 2 (so that I don't overwrite data). In total, I need to copy columns 3-81.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim col As Integer

For i = 3 To 81
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 2").Column(i).
```

Since I apply a function to every pasted column before copying and pasting the next one, I cannot simply denote the destination as column (i) because it will simply overwrite that last column of calculated data.

How can I change the destination so that I do not have this problem?

This question has been asked many times before however I cannot find my solution since I seem to be the only one using a loop and assigning col as i.

Comment: I really look forward to seeing the person who understands this question.

Comment: [Methods for Finding the Last Used Row or Column in a Worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet#t=201705082041081950548) - The fact that you are finding the last used column **while within a loop** does not affect the way to find it.

Comment: @Tehscript, meet Tim Williams...

Comment: @MacroMarc That was what I implied..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 3
For i = 3 To 81
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 2").Columns(j)
    j = j + 2
Next i
```

Comment: I don't get why the `j =j +2` part. Why not `j=j+1` ? Or also why not copying all columns at once and pasting them ?

Comment: With my particular data, I cannot transfer all columns at once because with each column that's pasted, I apply a function to create a new column of data directly right of it. j=j+1 would overwrite this new column of data that's beside it.